# Django и AJAX: некоторые проблемы

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, асинхронность

Доброго времени суток!

Решил углубиться в доселе неизведанные края: в питон, в джанго и всё этому сопутствующее.

Была поставлена задача достаточно простая:

***Состряпать страничку с текстовым полем, в которое необходимо ввести тест и тут же этот текст где-нибудь вывести, т.е. выполнить AJAX запрос.***

Хорошо. Сделано. Это не было сложным, если не брать в расчёт первичное знакомство с новыми технологиями. Но я решил пойти дальше и *добавить возможность сохранять введённые данные в БД.*

Это оказалось тоже достаточно простым и не заняло много времени.

*Вытащить данные из базы данных* так же не составило труда, как и обработать их в шаблоне для нужного вывода.

Но начались проблемы, когда я попытался прикрутить к этому делу AJAX, т.е. чтобы ***после ввода в текстовое поле изменения сразу же отображались на странице.***

По сути, это тоже сделано, однако работает оно не так гладко, как должно.

Оно, как нужно, обновляет данные в соответствии с введённым текстом, но делает это крайне нестабильно, т.е. иногда обновления не происходит вовсе.

Если судить по выводу терминала, то просто напросто не вызывается ajax_async_list в некоторые моменты. Причина такого поведения мне, увы, не ясна.

Ниже предоставлен репозиторий с исходниками.

https://gitlab.com/Aquinary/django-ajax

Буду рад любой помощи, благодарю!

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему подгружается не тот текст который был записан в базу данных, а тот который отправлен. в файле views.py 25 строка. Если текст не записан например из-за блокировки или ошибки, об этом не узнать.

Comment: Я понял о чём Вы. Иногда ajax_async_list вызывается перед ajax_async, т.е. а в ajax'e, насколько знаю, порядок выполнения запросов не гарантируется.

Comment: При активной работе так же будут проблемы с кодом, если идет только добавление, то лучше использовать ключ - значение. Смотрим не последнее добавленное, а уникальный ключ в базе данных. Так же можно просто обновлять одну единственную запись разделенную маркерами или формат json.